# Are there elementary forces acting in directions than 0 or 90 relative to their fields?

Tags: forces, field-theory, interactions

Some forces act in the same direction as their field orientation, like a gravitation. Other forces, for instance the force acting on a charged particle in a magnetic field, are perpendicular to that their field orientation.

Are there elementary forces acting in other directions than 0 or 90 relative to their fields?

If not, is there an explanation other than because that is what the product of the vectors is?

Comment: I don't know a lot about underlying concepts or mathematical theories.  From my perspective this is a really good question; but maybe I'm just missing something simple that explains it.  Either way, +1 from me.

Comment: Retarded potentials?

Answer (score 2):

The question is not well adapted to modern treatment of general relativity and quantum theory. In these theories, the notion of "force" is not very useful. Also, it supposes that the fields are characterized by a vector. This is not always the case. For example, general relativity uses a tensor field to describe space time. Staying with general relativity, the net effect can be different from an attraction on a line between the source and the test particle. For example, there is a frame dragging effect when the source is rotating, that adds components to the gravitational "force", to use your terms, that result in a total effect that is not purely directed towards the source (and of course not purely perpendicular to the source).